# How to graph multiple variables

Tags: r, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, data-visualization

I've been tasked with the challenge of creating ONE singular plot that entails a multitude of relevant given data.

There is one dependent variable vs three independent continuous variables, an independent discrete variable and four independent categorical variables. I have no idea where to start, and felt like isolating the variables into their relative *'category'* like previously stated was a good start. Is there a way to group these categorical variables especially into a single coefficient or modelled through multiple multiple-regression analysis'.

I was thinking that if i find each seperate category's probability of each individual categorical variable I may have a start. But where to from here.

Each variable is fundamentally important in affecting the dependent variable.

This preferably needs to be plotted in R. I have a solid understanding of R, but still have no idea where to start, especially considering that an xyplot probably wouldn't do this any justice.

Comment: Please tell us the objective of this plot: what are you trying to demonstrate or learn from it?

Comment: @whuber , its just supposed to summarise the data. I think a residual would be the best option?

Comment: Visualizing residuals is one way to summarize the data *with respect to a model.*  It does not summarize the data *per se.*

Comment: Can you add an example dataset to illustrate what you mean & so people have something to work with?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but possibly interesting. Without more information, here are some options you may consider:

- A simple [directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) showing the relation between the variables, probably a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (DAG), depending on what you need exactly. DAGs are closely related to the idea of [causal inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_inference)/[causal models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_model), so depending on your audience you might want to clarify if this is a causal diagram or not.
- If you have a model with some coefficients and confidence intervals, you can use a [forest plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest_plot#Example) (or dot-and-whisker plot) to plot them.
- If you don't have a model, you can conduct some [multiple correspondence analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correspondence_analysis) and visualize the result, e.g. with a [biplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biplot).

There are probably other options, depending on what you're after.